# Xml data referencing and flixel

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, flixel

I have started using XMLs for the first time in flixel, and I have run into some trouble.

I am trying to get the tileset out of this:

```
<Ground tileset="Tiles" exportMode="CSV">

//some code

</Ground>
```

I have tried:
Ground.tileset and Ground.@tileset, this may be a very simple solution... but I haven't used XMLs very much.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you have just to use an [`XML`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/XML.html) object like this :

```
var xml:XML = 
    <Ground tileset="Tiles" exportMode="CSV">
        <!-- some code -->
    </Ground>
;

trace(xml.@tileset);    // gives : Tiles
```

Hope that can help.